# How to save the position of the dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to save the current position of the `dialog` window opened so that when I bring it back up, it will go back to the last position. This is my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSk6L/935/  as you can see, after minimize, the window goes down, but if I maximize it goes to a set position and height. Any solutions to tell the `dialog` box the previous position on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a trick with your code, may be help you, it will save position even if you drag it:

```
<div id="window" data-top="" data-left="" data-height="">HEYYYY</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        var d = $('#window').dialog({
            draggable: true,
            height: 200,
            title: 'Results',
            open: function( event, ui ) { 
                $('#resultId').attr('data-top',$('.ui-dialog').css('top')); 
                $('#resultId').attr('data-left',$('.ui-dialog').css('left')); 
                $('#resultId').attr('data-height',$('.ui-dialog').css('height'));
            },
            dragStop: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#resultId').attr('data-top',$('.ui-dialog').css('top')); 
                $('#resultId').attr('data-left',$('.ui-dialog').css('left')); 
                $('#resultId').attr('data-height',$('.ui-dialog').css('height'));
            }
        }).attr('id', 'resultId');

        var titlebar = d.parents('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar');     
        var min= $('<button/>', {
                text: '-',
                id: 'minButton',
                click: function() {
                    var top = $('.ui-dialog').css('top');
                    $('#resultId').parents('.ui-dialog').animate({
                        height: '40px',
                        top: $(window).height() - 90
                    }, 50);
                $(this).hide();
                $('#maxButton').show();
                }
            });

         var max = $('<button/>', {
                text: '+',
                id: 'maxButton',
                click: function() {
                    $('#resultId').parents('.ui-dialog').animate({
                        //set the positioning to center the dialog - 200 is equal to height of dialog
                        top: $('#resultId').attr('data-top'),
                        left:$('#resultId').attr('data-left'),
                        height: $('#resultId').attr('data-height'),
                    }, 50);
                $(this).hide();
                $('#minButton').show();
                }
            });

        min.appendTo(titlebar).css({'margin-left':'50%','width':'30px'});
        max.appendTo(titlebar).css({'margin-left':'50%','width':'30px'}).hide();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaya Is it possibe to get the height, i tried to add: $('#resultId').attr('data-height',$('.ui-dialog').css('height'));  and set the height: $('#resultId').attr('data-height')  , but didnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I would add an event listener to the `X` button such that, when it's clicked, I measure the `.offsetLeft` and `.offsetTop` of the element. These two properties will give you the amount of space between the dialog box and its container.

Something like:

```
var boxLeft;
var boxTop;
var box = document.querySelector(".ui-dialog");
var button = document.querySelector(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  boxLeft = box.offsetLeft;
  boxTop = box.offsetTop;
});

(function whenTheBoxIsOpenedAgain(){
  box.style.left = boxLeft + "px";
  box.style.top = boxTop + "px";
}())
```